# Configuring aws eks using terraform failed: NodeCreationFailure: Instances failed to join the kubernetes cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

Below is terraform resource definition for configuring k8s on aws eks:

1. `eks.tf`

```
resource "aws_eks_cluster" "airflow" {
  name     = "airflow"
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.eks_cluster_role.arn
  tags = {
    "Cluster" = "airflow"
  }
  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids = aws_subnet.private_subnets[*].id
    security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.eks_cluster_sg.id]

    endpoint_private_access = true
    endpoint_public_access  = true
  }
}

resource "aws_eks_node_group" "workers" {
  cluster_name    = aws_eks_cluster.airflow.name
  node_group_name = "workers"
  node_role_arn   = aws_iam_role.eks_node_role.arn
  subnet_ids      = aws_subnet.private_subnets[*].id

  tags = {
    "nodegroup-role" = "worker"
  }

  scaling_config {
    desired_size = 3
    max_size     = 3
    min_size     = 1
  }

  launch_template {
    id = aws_launch_template.workers.id
    version = aws_launch_template.workers.latest_version
  }

  capacity_type = "ON_DEMAND"
}

resource "aws_launch_template" "workers" {
  name_prefix   = "workers-"
  instance_type = "t3.medium"
  block_device_mappings {
    device_name = "/dev/xvda"
    ebs {
      volume_size = 10
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "eks_cluster_role" {
  name = "eks-cluster-role"

  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17",
    Statement = [{
      Action = "sts:AssumeRole",
      Effect = "Allow",
      Principal = {
        Service = "eks.amazonaws.com"
      }
    }]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "eks_node_role" {
  name = "eks-node-role"

  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17",
    Statement = [{
      Action = "sts:AssumeRole",
      Effect = "Allow",
      Principal = {
        Service = "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      }
    }]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "eks_cluster_policy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSClusterPolicy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.eks_cluster_role.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "eks_node_policy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.eks_node_role.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "eks_cni_policy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.eks_node_role.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "eks_ecr_policy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly"
  role       = aws_iam_role.eks_node_role.name
}
```

2. `networks.tf`

```
resource "aws_vpc" "eks_vpc" {
  cidr_block = var.vpc_cidr_block
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnets" {
  count           = length(var.subnets_cidr_blocks)
  cidr_block      = var.subnets_cidr_blocks[count.index]
  availability_zone = element(["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b", "us-east-1c"], count.index) # Use different AZs
  vpc_id          = aws_vpc.eks_vpc.id
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false
}

resource "aws_security_group" "eks_cluster_sg" {
  name_prefix = "eks-cluster-"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.eks_vpc.id
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "eks_cluster_ingress" {
  type        = "ingress"
  from_port   = 443
  to_port     = 443
  protocol    = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"] # Allow inbound traffic from anywhere (for EKS control plane)
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.eks_cluster_sg.id
}
```

3. `variables.tf`

```
variable "region" {
  description = "AWS region"
}

variable "vpc_cidr_block" {
  description = "CIDR block for VPC"
}

variable "subnets_cidr_blocks" {
  description = "List of CIDR blocks for subnets"
  type        = list(string)
}
```

4. `dev.tfvars`

```
region            = "us-east-1"
vpc_cidr_block    = "10.0.0.0/16"
subnets_cidr_blocks = ["10.0.1.0/24", "10.0.2.0/24", "10.0.3.0/24"]
```

When I run `terraform apply -var-file=dev.tfvars`,

1. `aws_eks_cluster.airflow` --> creation complete
2. `aws_eks_node_group.workers` --> Fail

   - error

     ```
     ╷
     │ Error: waiting for EKS Node Group (airflow:workers) to create: unexpected state 'CREATE_FAILED', wanted target 'ACTIVE'. last error: 1 error occurred:
     │       * i-074382736a67e8f94, i-0e517a55fcc7fe2ca, i-0f3ed963c5f1b63bf: NodeCreationFailure: Instances failed to join the kubernetes cluster
     ```

I have no idea why creating `aws_eks_node_group.workers` failed.

Comment: I suspect this might be due to the fact that your private subnets cannot reach the AWS services in public zone/public internet, but I might be wrong.